# How to invoke a function in parent component from deeply nested child component using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
    }

    getChildrenValues(){
        console.log("Children values");
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            Parent 

            <Component1>

                <Component2>
                    <Child />   

                </Component2>

            </Component1>

        </div>
    }
}


class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
    }

    clicked(){
        this.props.dispatch({type: "InvokeParent"});
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            <button onClick = {this.clicked}>Click Here</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

how to invoke getChildrenValues function from "Child" component. I am trying to get all children values from parent component and submit but I do not know how to trigger that function in redux. In flux I used to do addChangeListener and trigger that function.

Comment: What do you want this parent function to do in your real situation? Is it going to affect your global state? In your current example code I would say don't use redux at all, just pass the function down as a prop and invoke the prop on click

Comment: By invoking that function I will invoke children common methods like getValue  - which returns state of child component and submit the data.

Answer (score 2):

Just based on your example, I would say this situation won't involve redux at all. Redux is a tool for managing global state. Nothing in this example is touching state.

For this example code to work pass your method down as a prop and invoke it on click. This can be messy if depending on how nested the child component is.

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
    }

    getChildrenValues(){
        console.log("Children values");
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            Parent 

            <Component1>

                <Component2>
                    <Child invokeParent={this.getChildrenValues} />   

                </Component2>

            </Component1>

        </div>
    }
}


class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
    }

    clicked(){
        this.props.dispatch({type: "InvokeParent"});
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            <button onClick = {this.props.invokeParent}>Click Here</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes as you said the code would become messy that is why I am trying to dispatch an action from child component and get all children values of the main parent and submit the values.