# Change checked attribute of controlled checkbox (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I am new to React and am probably lacking the correct terminology to find a solution to my problem. It cannot be that hard.

I am building a simple app which displays a set of questions, one question at a time. After answering one question, the next question is shown.

I have a component `Question` that renders 3 checkboxes, each checkbox represents one possible `answer` to the Question.

```
{this.props.question.answers.map((answer, index) => {
  return (
    <li className="Question__answer" key={answer.id}>
      <label className="Question__answer-label">
        <input
          className="Question__answer-checkbox"
          type="checkbox"
          value={index}
          onChange={this.props.setAnswer}
          defaultChecked={false} />
        {answer.answer}
      </label>
    </li>

    ...

    <button className="Question__next" type="button" onClick={this.props.onNext} disabled={this.props.isDisabled}>
        Next question
      </button>
  )
})}
```

Inside my main component `Quiz` I call the component like this:

`<Question step={this.state.step} question={this.state.questions[this.state.step]} setAnswer={this.setAnswer} onNext={this.onNext} isDisabled={this.isDisabled()} />`

`onNext` is my function which increments `this.state.step` in order to display the next question:

```
onNext(event) {
    this.setState({step: this.state.step + 1});
}
```

Everything works fine, except: When the next question is displayed, I want all 3 checkboxes to be unchecked again. Currently they remember their checked state from the previously answered question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke a function in parent component from deeply nested child component using redux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091627/how-to-invoke-a-function-in-parent-component-from-deeply-nested-child-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the thing is that React renders its components such that only the components that changed are rendered. Since nothing has changed about the checkboxes checked attribute after rerendering they stay in their previous state.

What you should do is toggle the checkbox state on click in the `setAnswer` function and pass this as a prop to the Question component.

Something like

```
this.state {
   checkedAttr: ["false", "false", "false"]
}
```

Pass it on like

```
<Question step={this.state.step} question={this.state.questions[this.state.step]} setAnswer={this.setAnswer} onNext={this.onNext} isDisabled={this.isDisabled()} checkedAttr={this.state.checkedAttr} />
```

Use them in the checkboxes state as

```
{this.props.question.answers.map((answer, index) => {
  return (
    <li className="Question__answer" key={answer.id}>
      <label className="Question__answer-label">
        <input
          className="Question__answer-checkbox"
          type="checkbox"
          value={index}
          checked={this.props.checkedAttr[index]}
          onChange={this.props.setAnswer}
          defaultChecked={false} />
        {answer.answer}
      </label>
    </li>

    ...

    <button className="Question__next" type="button" onClick={this.props.onNext} disabled={this.props.isDisabled}>
        Next question
      </button>
  )
})}
```

In the `onNext` function just reset the states `checkedAttr` to `false`.

Comment: @maze Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

On the `Question` Component use the `componentWillReceiveProps` method like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    likesIncreasing: nextProps.likeCount > this.props.likeCount
  });
}
```

According to the docs :

> componentWillReceiveProps will be Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not called for the initial render.

fetch the received step from the `Question` component and update its state to show the new `Question`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! So I should introduce a state inside my `Questions` component? I thought it would be best practice to keep this component stateless and pass all information to it via props from the parent `Quiz` component? I am not quite sure how to implement your suggestion.

Comment: @maze Yes of course ! But in this case your Question component is continuously changing with each step change, so you should either have multiple stateless `Question`s or have a single stateful one.

Comment: So, I added this.state.step to `Question` component; then `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { this.setState({step: nextProps.step });` but the result is the same: Quesions do change, but the checkboxes remember their previous state... What am I doing wrong?