# How to make a checkbox behave like a radio button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to make the bootstrap check boxes to behave like a radio button in react ?. I have a dynamically loading rows in a table and each rows contain accept and reject check boxes, I want these checkbox to behave like a radio button. I cannot use radio button so need a way to make check boxes to behave like radio button.

```
                    <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="custom-control-input"
                        id={page + item.RowKey + "Accept"}
                        name={page + item.RowKey + "Accept"}/>

                      <label
                        className="custom-control-label"
                        htmlFor={page + item.RowKey + "Accept"}>

                        Accept
                      </label>
                   </div>
                   <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="custom-control-input"
                        id={page + item.RowKey + "Reject"} />
                      <label
                        className="custom-control-label"
                        htmlFor={page + item.RowKey + "Reject"}>

                        Reject
                      </label>
                   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ref` with checkboxes, and `onClick` for each of them, by using `ref` you can unCheck the box.

Here is some documentation on ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: could you please share a code snippet for a react hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use state to manipulate this.
Like:

Below Link have a full explaination of it

[Change checked attribute of controlled checkbox (React)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227084/change-checked-attribute-of-controlled-checkbox-react)